# Azure Data Factory V2 exploring pipeline dependencies

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working with quite a lot of pipelines, and with that involves a lot of dependencies between pipelines.

This isn't ideal for a couple reasons:

- It gets harder to know if you change something in one pipeline, what other pipelines could be affected
- Being able to document the overall data factory structure

Ideally I should be able to "select" a random pipeline and be able to know what pipelines dependencies it has for both before and after execution.

I was thinking about using the Data Factory SDK's to try and build the dependency structure of all my pipelines. But thought I would chuck this out there to see if anyone has discovered any solutions for this, or have any ideas before going down a rabbit hole.

I appreciate any advice.

Cheers, Brendan

Comment: Putting the raw Azure ARM template into a Json text file can be useful to find and search for this kind of info.  You can download the main ARM json template and all its linked templates in one zip file.  Useful for Dev vs Prod comparisons also.  Choose the Export from resource group to get the "now" or "as is" template.  If you are in GIT mode how you do this is ambiguous. In general you go to ARM Template and then Export Resource Template in the Data Factory Designer to get a text searchable version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brendan, our ADF is connected to git and so when I need to know what will be affected if I change the pipeline with say name `somePipelineName`, I goto git bash and type out

```
grep --color=always -4 "somePipelineName" *
```

on the pipelines folder

This helps me find all places from where the pipeline may be called.

**Update: 2020-09-17**

I noticed today that we now have the related pipelines listing

[image]

Comment: This is basically what we have been doing, which doesn't feel like the best thing to be doing. It would be great if there was something more elegant.

Comment: @Brendan the idea's already started by MS- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/40974952-lineage-across-every-component-withing-adf

Comment: Oh awesome! I didn't see that. I'll be sure to keep my eye on that one.

Comment: @Brendan I see related pipelines now in my adf; added screenshot to answer

Comment: did that just get released?

Comment: @Brendan I see it since couple of days

Answer (score 0):

using Az.Datafactory module (in Powershell...)
with a particular pipeline object from Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline

$azDFPipelines = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName = "$azRG" -DataFactoryName = "$AzADFName"

the "Activities" property can be expanded, as can its DependsOn property:

$azDFPipelines[X] | select ADFName -ExpandProperty Activities | select adfName, name, description -expandproperty DependsOn

ADFName: name of the pipeline
Name:  name of the activity/object in the pipeline
Description: description of the activity/object in the pipeline
DependsOn: data from the activity/object's dependencies (e.g., the objects it's "connected" to).

I've got a script that does this, and runs the output thru out-gridview. From there, I can then add different criteria fields to help look for stuff throughout the entire pipeline collection on my "server". Kinda helpful, if not really very user-friendly.

```
import-module Az.Accounts
import-module Az.DataFactory
$azAcct = Connect-AzAccount -subscription 'your_subscription_name'
#$azRgName, $azDFName are "empirically determined"
enter code here
$azDFPipelines = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "$azRGname" -DataFactoryName "$azDFName" 
###need to coerce the Name property to ADFName because it's also a member of the Activities object/property...
$adf = $azDFPipelines | select-object @{N='ADFName';E={$_.name}},`
@{N='Activities';E={$_.Activities}}

Next-level would be making it essentially walk the tree in a given pipeline or from a pipeline's specific pipeline object, and spit out graphviz "dot" or Mermaid graph language .md (or .vsdx...)

###expand Activities, and also select just a few properties from Activities:
$adflist = $adf | select ADFName -ExpandProperty Activities | select ADFName, name, description, notebookpath, additionalproperties
$adfList | out-gridview
```

Next-level would be making it essentially walk the tree in a given pipeline or from a pipeline's specific pipeline object, and spit out graphviz "dot" or Mermaid graph language .md (or .vsdx...)

###expand Activities, and also select just a few properties from Activities:
$adflist = $adf | select ADFName -ExpandProperty Activities | select ADFName, name, description, notebookpath, additionalproperties
$adfList | out-gridview

the DependsOn can be extracted from the additionalproperties collection...

the AdditionalProperties has the name of the "next" thing to be run in it, what it is, etc.

Like SSIS, execution flow through a ADF pipeline is "parallel" and are invoked non-deterministically, unless they're connected to each other serially. same goes for connected objects - they're invoked "in parallel" unless they're connected in series.

Comment: This is really cool. I am working on doing something a little similar. I am having trouble with trying to access parts of typeProperties inside AdditionalProperties. Do you have any idea how to do this?